# How to hanlde UI rotation in Marmalade

Tags: ios, marmalade

I want to know how to handle UI rotation. I have requirement to chang my UI layout when user rotates UI from Potrait to Landscape or vice versa. Let me know which event I need to handle and how do I get device height and width for both kind of rotation and adjust my UI.

I am also interested that if I use various layout then will it be adjusted automatically on UI rotation. Typical case is let say I have created UI using layouts which display two components on main screen, left side one list and right side content of particular item of list (this is same as explorer on windows). In this case if I rotate my UI then will it adjust correctly or I need to handle explicitly.

Please share your inputs on this asap.

Thank you very much in advance for your support.

Regards,
Premal Panchal
.

Answer (score 0):

`Marmalade` handles `Portrait` to `Landscape` and vice-versa movement automatically, so You don't need to code it.

Answer (score 0):

Register for the S3E_SURFACE_SCREENSIZE callback and then you can get notification when the screen size/orientation has changed:

```
s3eSurfaceRegister( S3E_SURFACE_SCREENSIZE, (s3eCallback)ScreenSizeOrientationChanged );


void ScreenSizeOrientationChanged( s3eSurfaceOrientation *orien, void *pUserData )
{
    s3eDebugTracePrintf( "Orientation Changed: width=%d, height=%d, surfacewidth=%d, surfaceheight=%d, blitdirection=%s", orien->m_Width, orien->m_Height, Iw2DGetSurfaceWidth(), Iw2DGetSurfaceHeight(), S3E_SURFACE_BLIT_DIR_ROT180 ? "180" : "0" );

    CGame *pGame = (CGame *)pUserData;
    if( pGame )
    {
        pGame->ReCalculateScreenSize( orien->m_Width, orien->m_Height );
    }
}

s3eSurfaceUnRegister( S3E_SURFACE_SCREENSIZE, (s3eCallback)ScreenSizeOrientationChanged );
```

You will notice that the GetSurfaceWidth/Height methods still report the original orientation values, so use the values passsed in the s3eSurfaceOrientation structure